# Why doesn't GCM HTTPS work with nginx?

Tags: security, openbsd, openssl, https

Since these two are using GCM ([Galois/Counter Mode)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode):

```
www.ssllabs.com: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
www.google.com: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

We wanted to make our webserver's HTTPS connection more secure (Don't look at the self-signed certificate, that doesn't count right now...).

We are using an OpenBSD 5.4 64bit OS, and the `openssl ciphers` command says that it supports the `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384` cipher. On client side there is Firefox 30 at least.

So here is how we setup the HTTPS server:

```
# generate self signed certificate
    openssl genrsa -aes256 -out /etc/ssl/private/server.key 4096
    openssl req -new -key /etc/ssl/private/server.key -out /etc/ssl/private/server.csr
    openssl x509 -sha512 -req -days 365 -in /etc/ssl/private/server.csr -signkey /etc/ssl/private/server.key -out /etc/ssl/server.crt
```

The config:

```
vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
```

But Firefox says (I translated it from my language..):

> A connection to the www.foo.hu is interrupted

and [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) says:

> Assessment failed: Failed to communicate with the secure server

- How can we set GCM in nginx?
- Why couldn't a fresh Firefox connect via HTTPS to `www.foo.hu` (`ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`, TLSv1.2)?

It can connect to `www.ssllabs.com` via HTTPS (`ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`, TLSv1.2), so maybe it's not a client side problem?

```
[user@localhost ~] openssl s_client -connect www.foo.hu:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = HU, CN = www.foo.hu
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = HU, CN = www.foo.hu
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=HU/CN=www.foo.hu
   i:/C=HU/CN=www.foo.hu
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.... here goes the cert..
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=HU/CN=www.foo.hu
issuer=/C=HU/CN=www.foo.hu
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2137 bytes and written 389 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: ...bla-bla
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: ...bla-bla
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
...bla-bla

    Start Time: 1404296744
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
read:errno=0
[user@localhost ~]
```

Comment: nginx error logs?

Comment: Do you know it's GCM that causes the problem? Choice of curves for ECDHE or hash algorithm for the RSA signature are potential failure points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the cipher suite was the final solution.

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256;
```

The problem was that Firefox 30 doesn't supports the mentioned cipher yet.